# Data transfer between C++ class and QAbstractTableModel

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am building a GUI for my existing code. I have a memory class that holds most of my data and I want to display the data in a Qtable. I also want the table to update as my data updates.

The structure is as follows:

```
//memory.hpp
class Memory
{
    //Holds and updates the data.


}

//memory_model.hpp
class MemoryModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MemoryModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
};
```

what is the best way to communicate data from memory down to the memory_model. And how do I trigger data changes in memory_model when data changes in the memory?

Answer (score 0):

How to trigger data changes depends on how the data is changed.

For example, before you insert any new rows into your back-end C++ memory class, you should call [beginInsertRows()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginInsertRows) on your `MemoryModel` object.  Then you'd do the actual changing of the state of your `Memory` C++ data structure, and then you'd call [endInsertRows()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#endInsertRows) to let the table-model know that you've finished inserting all the rows you intended to insert.

A similar calling-pattern exists for inserting/removing columns (with `beginInsertColumns()`/`endInsertColumns()` and `beginRemoveColumns()`/`endRemoveColumns()`), moving rows or colors (with `beginMoveRows()`/`endMoveRows()`/`beginMoveColumns()`/`endMoveColumns()`, or simply doing a full throw-all-cached-data-away-and-repopulate-from-scratch (with `beginResetModel()`/`endResetModel()`).

If you don't need to add/remove/move rows or columns, but just want to have the table update/refresh/requery the contents of a particular cell or set of cells, you can make that happen by having your MemoryModel emit a [dataChanged()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged) signal for the cells that you want to the table to update.